# Проблема с конструктором класса-наследника

Tags: c++, конструктор, visual-studio-2010

Здравствуйте, решая задачу на наследование, столкнулся с такой проблемой: компилятор выдает ошибку, когда я определяю конструктор унаследованного класса. Совсем не могу понять, что я делаю не так, хотя перечитал главу в книге тщательно и вроде задача несложная, но как только этот конструктор появляется в файле с определением методов этого класса и базового, то появляются проблемы. Я работаю в Visual Studio 2010.

Вот код:

// Заголовочный файл

```
 #ifndef CLASSIC_H_
    #define CLASSIC_H_

    #include <string>

class Cd
{
private:
    char performers[50];
    char label[20];
    int selections;
    double playtime;
public:
    Cd(char *, char *, int, double);
    Cd(const Cd &);
    Cd() { performers[0] = '\0'; label[0] = '\0'; selections = 0; playtime = 0.0; }
    virtual ~Cd();
    virtual void Report() const;
    Cd & operator= (const Cd &);
};



class Classic : public Cd
{
private:
    std::string primWork;
public:
    Classic(const char * s1, const char * s2, int n, double x, const std::string & s3);
    Classic(const Cd &, const std::string &);
    Classic();
    ~Classic();
    virtual void Report() const;
};

#endif
```

// Определение методов

```
#include <iostream>
#include "classic.h"

Cd::Cd(const char * s1,const char * s2, int n, double x)
{
    strncpy(performers, s1, 49);
    strncpy(label, s2, 19);
    selections = n;
    playtime = x;
}

Cd::Cd(const Cd & c)
{
    strcpy(performers, c.performers);
    strcpy(label, c.label);
    selections = c.selections;
    playtime = c.playtime;
}

Cd & Cd::operator=(const Cd & c)
{
    if (this == &c)
        return *this;
    strcpy(performers, c.performers);
    strcpy(label, c.label);
    selections = c.selections;
    playtime = c.playtime;
    return *this;
}

void Cd::Report() const
{
    std::cout << "Performers: " << performers << "; Label: " << label << "; Selections: " << selections << "; Playtime: " << playtime << std::endl;
}

Cd::~Cd()
{
}


Classic::Classic(const char * s1, const char * s2, int n, double x, const std::string & s3) : Cd(s1, s2, n, x), primWork(s3)
{
}
```

// Программу для тестирование еще даже не написал

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "classic.h"

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

Стоит мне удалить конструктор:

```
Classic::Classic(const char * s1, const char * s2, int n, double x, const std::string & s3) : Cd(s1, s2, n, x), primWork(s3)
{
}
```

Консольное окно выводится без всяких дополнительных сообщений и написано Build Succeeded. Добавляю конструктор и пишет Build Failed.

Вот весь текст, что написан компилятором:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: cd, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 15.08.2017 14:49:25.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\cd.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  Methods.cpp
1>c:\users\константин\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cd\cd\methods.cpp(6): warning C4996: 'strncpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strncpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string.h(188) : see declaration of 'strncpy'
1>c:\users\константин\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cd\cd\methods.cpp(7): warning C4996: 'strncpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strncpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string.h(188) : see declaration of 'strncpy'
1>c:\users\константин\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cd\cd\methods.cpp(14): warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string.h(105) : see declaration of 'strcpy'
1>c:\users\константин\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cd\cd\methods.cpp(15): warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string.h(105) : see declaration of 'strcpy'
1>c:\users\константин\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cd\cd\methods.cpp(24): warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string.h(105) : see declaration of 'strcpy'
1>c:\users\константин\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cd\cd\methods.cpp(25): warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string.h(105) : see declaration of 'strcpy'
1>  Generating Code...
1>  Compiling...
1>  test.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>Methods.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall Classic::Report(void)const " (?Report@Classic@@UBEXXZ)
1>Methods.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall Classic::~Classic(void)" (??1Classic@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __thiscall Classic::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GClassic@@UAEPAXI@Z)
1>C:\Users\Константин\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\cd\Debug\cd.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.40
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Так происходит с любой задачей на наследование. Сам разобраться в этом не смог...

Comment: Вы спрашиваете или утверждаете  "Стоит мне удалить конструктор:" ?

Comment: @V.March, он повествует, что после удаления сборка проходит нормально

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с того, что у вас объявлен конструктор

```
Cd(char *, char *, int, double);
```

а реализован совсем другой -

```
Cd::Cd(const char * s1,const char * s2, int n, double x)
{
    strncpy(performers, s1, 49);
    strncpy(label, s2, 19);
    selections = n;
    playtime = x;
}
```

Разницу видите?

Еще у вас нет реализации деструктора `~Classic` и функции `Classic::Report`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, исправил прототип конструктора и доопределил все оставшиеся методы унаследованного класса. Оказывается если ты объявил класс но не определял его методы, то ошибки нет, но как только написал реализацию как минимум одного, то уже выдает ошибку. Раньше этого не знал. Спасибо еще раз.